# error in the backend

Tags: admin, error

```
Array ( [type] => 2 [message] => chdir() [function.chdir]: No such file or directory (errno 2) [file] => /home/studious/public_html/maal-php/lib/Varien/Io/File.php [line] => 567 )
```

The above error will display when i upload the image on attribute. Attribute image is added perfectly but the above code is also inserted.
when i select the particular image then its show like

```
"media/image/abc.pngArray ( [type] => 2 [message] => chdir() [function.chdir]: No such file or directory (errno 2) [file] => /home/studious/public_html/maal-php/lib/Varien/Io/File.php [line] => 567 )"
```

So in the front end attribute images are not showing

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It has to be a `print_r` somewhere in your code which outputs this message.

Comment: how can i find this? I am totally new to this

Comment: Search in the source code everywhere. `grep -r "print_r" .` under linux or use your IDE's search functions.